# Varnish stopped working after changing ip address of backend

Tags: varnish

A month ago I installed Varnish and Drupal on separate machines and could see that varnish was serving pages. A few days back I changed the ip address of the backend in my default.vcl to point to another machine and since then Varnish has stopped responding to requests. If you are wondering if I restarted Varnish, yes I did restart it.

What I find strange is that varnishlog doesn't display the ping and pong. A ps aux displays that Varnish is running. But visiting the ip address in my browser doesn't return any page.

```
[root@bw2 sridhar]# ps aux | grep varnish
root      3672  0.0  0.0  93660  1452 ?        Ss   10:24   0:00 /usr/sbin/varnishd -P /var/run/varnish.pid -a :80 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -T 127.0.0.1:6082 -t 120 -w 1,1000, -u varnish -g varnish -p thread_pool_add_delay 2 -p thread_pools 2 -p thread_pool_min 400 -p thread_pool_max 4000 -p session_linger 50 -p sess_workspace 262144 -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,1G
root      5845  0.0  0.0   4356   732 pts/0    S+   10:45   0:00 grep varnish
```

Here is my default.vcl (if it helps). 
    backend default {
        .host = "37.139.24.12";
        .port = "80";
        .connect_timeout = 1s;
        .first_byte_timeout = 5s;
        .between_bytes_timeout = 2s;
    }

Visiting the backend ip in a browser displays pages. So I guess that Varnish for some reason has become stubborn!

Comment: when you restart varnish do you see any entries in /var/log/messages or varnish log?? i guess user process is not running, whats in here: netstat -tulnp | grep varnish

Comment: @ADM I see these in /var/log/messages                            Jun 12 11:51:41 bookingwire2 varnishd[10658]: child (10937) Started
Jun 12 11:51:41 bookingwire2 varnishd[10658]: Child (10937) said 
Jun 12 11:51:41 bookingwire2 varnishd[10658]: Child (10937) said Child starts
Jun 12 11:51:41 bookingwire2 varnishd[10658]: Child (10937) died signal=11
repeated several times

Comment: [root@bw2 sridhar]# netstat -tulnp | grep varnish
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6082              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      10658/varnishd

Comment: is your config clean? varnishd -C -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl

Comment: @ADM I don't getit. I ran this command and it spewed out a lot of lines. Should I pastbin it for you?

Comment: no, if config is broken it will show you where is the error, try to remove options like: -w 1,1000, -p thread_pools 2; or even better try to start without options.

Comment: Seems Clean. I don't see any errors in the output.

Comment: I restarted Varnish I now see a new message n /var/log/messages       Jun 12 12:17:03 bookingwire2 kernel: varnishd[12941]: segfault at abbbc4f0 ip 080711a0 sp abbbc4f0 error 6 in varnishd[8048000+63000]

Comment: One more : Jun 12 12:17:03 bookingwire2 varnishd[12921]: Pushing vcls failed: CLI communication error (hdr)